# Submit button only works when first 2 fields are empty

Tags: javascript, html

http://windowsnaarlinux.nl/#distrokiezer -- Temporarily replaced the page with a PHP version, here's the javascript version: http://windowsnaarlinux.nl/pages/distrokiezer.html

---

Whenever you leave one of the first two fields empty and click the submit button (captioned *Bevestigen*), you get a warning and the script ends, as it's supposed to do. But when you fill in the first two fields, and then click the submit, nothing what so ever happens. There doesn't pop up any alert, as it should. Neither does there appear any kind of error or warning in Chrome's javascript console.

The original page (the one of wich jQuery loads the content into `div.window#content`) is located here: http://windowsnaarlinux.nl/pages/distrokiezer.html 
Might be worth mentioning that it worked fine before, and that I honestly don't have a clue myself what I did to break it.

---

... I just noticed I forgot the part where it outputs the result to the user when I rewrote the script >.<

Comment: Can you post the javascript wich shows the alert?

Comment: @George It's just in the source of the `distrokiezer.htm` file. But here's the Javascript seperately anyway: http://pastebin.com/ikLPpBRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the warnings only appear when a field is left empty, because the first two fields are text input when left empty there value is nothing like your code checks for:

```
if ((stop == false) && (document.getElementById('q1a').value == ''))
```

However when your select boxes aren't modified their default value is the value of the first option causing the javascript not to trigger.

Put something like this as the first option in all your select forms:

```
<option value="" selected="selected">Please select an option</option>
```

This ensures that the default value is nothing. Just be sure to stop people (like you are already) using that option as it most likely means nothing.

Further to my comment this is why currently no alert is being recieved when two checkboxes are being filled.

Is the entire script....

```
    var distros = new Array('ubuntu', 'ubuntu-lts', 'mint', 'mintdebian', 'mintlxde', 'mintdebianxfce', 'elementary', 'debian-stable', 'debian-unstable', 'debian-testing', 'fedora', 'fedorakde', 'fedoralxde', 'fedoraxfce', 'centos', 'archlinux', 'puppylinux', 'lucidpuppy', 'crunchbang', 'dsl', 'tinycore', 'pinguyos', /*'gentoo',*/ 'mandriva', 'mageia', 'lubuntu', 'xubuntu', 'kubuntu', 'chakra', 'slackware', 'zorin', 'bodhi', 'vector', 'antix', 'opensuse');

    function zoekDistro()
    {
        try
        {
            var stop = false;

            //q1a
            var q1a = parseInt(document.getElementById('q1a').value);
            if ((stop == false) && (document.getElementById('q1a').value == ''))
            {
                alert('Geen antwoord opgegeven bij vraag 1a!');
                stop = true;
            }
            if (stop == false)
            {
                if (q1a < 1600)
                {
                    dumpDistro('pinguyos');
                    dumpDistro('mintkde');
                    dumpDistro('kubuntu');
                }
                if (q1a < 1400)
                {
                    dumpDistro('mint');
                    dumpDistro('fedorakde');
                    dumpDistro('fedora');
                    dumpDistro('pinguyos');
                    dumpDistro('chakra');
                    dumpDistro('ubuntu');
                    dumpDistro('mandriva');
                    dumpDistro('opensuse');
                }
                if (q1a < 1200)
                {
                    dumpDistro('ubuntu-lts');
                }
                if (q1a < 1000)
                {
                    dumpDistro('mintdebian');
                    dumpDistro('debian-stable');
                    dumpDistro('debian-testing');
                    dumpDistro('debian-unstable');
                    dumpDistro('mageia');
                    dumpDistro('xubuntu');
                    dumpDistro('crunchbang');
                }
                if (q1a < 800)
                {
                    dumpDistro('mintlxde');
                    dumpDistro('mintdebianxfce');
                    dumpDistro('elementary');
                    dumpDistro('fedoralxde');
                    dumpDistro('fedoraxfce');
                    dumpDistro('centos');
                    dumpDistro('archbang');
                    dumpDistro('zorin');
                }
                if (q1a < 600)
                {
                    dumpDistro('lubuntu');
                    dumpDistro('slackware');
                    dumpDistro('archlinux');
                }
                if (q1a < 400)
                {
                    dumpDistro('vector');
                    dumpDistro('gentoo');
                }
                if (q1a < 300)
                {
                    dumpDistro('antix');
                    dumpDistro('lucidpuppy');
                    dumpDistro('bodhi');
                }
                if (q1a < 200)
                {
                    dumpDistro('puppylinux');
                    dumpDistro('dsl');
                }
                if (q1a < 100)
                {
                    dumpDistro('tinycore');
                }
            }
            //q2a
            var q1b = parseInt(document.getElementById('q1b').value);
            if ((stop == false) && (document.getElementById('q1b').value == ''))
            {
                alert('Geen antwoord opgegeven bij vraag 1b!');
                stop = true;
            }
            if (stop == false)
            {
                if (q1b < 2000)
                {
                    dumpDistro('pinguyos');
                }
                if (q1b < 1600)
                {
                    dumpDistro('kubuntu');
                    dumpDistro('ubuntu');
                }
                if (q1b < 1400)
                {
                    dumpDistro('fedora');
                    dumpDistro('fedorakde');
                }
                if (q1b < 1000)
                {
                    dumpDistro('ubuntu-lts');
                    dumpDistro('mint');
                    dumpDistro('debian-unstable');
                    dumpDistro('mandriva');
                    dumpDistro('mageia');
                    dumpDistro('xubuntu');
                    dumpDistro('chakra');
                    dumpDistro('opensuse');
                }
                if (q1b < 800)
                {
                    dumpDistro('mintlxde');
                    dumpDistro('lubuntu');
                }
                if (q1b < 700)
                {
                    dumpDistro('elementary');
                }
                if (q1b < 512)
                {
                    dumpDistro('mintdebian');
                    dumpDistro('debian-testing');
                    dumpDistro('fedoralxde');
                    dumpDistro('fedoraxfce');
                    dumpDistro('crunchbang');
                }
                if (q1b < 400)
                {
                    dumpDistro('mintdebianxfce');
                    dumpDistro('debian-stable');
                    dumpDistro('archbang');
                    dumpDistro('archlinux');
                    dumpDistro('centos');
                    dumpDistro('zorin');
                    dumpDistro('vector');
                }
                if (q1b < 256)
                {
                    dumpDistro('gentoo');
                    dumpDistro('slackware');
                }
                if (q1b < 128)
                {
                    dumpDistro('bodhi');
                    dumpDistro('puppylinux');
                }
                if (q1b < 64)
                {
                    dumpDistro('lucidpuppy');
                    dumpDistro('antix');
                }
                if (q1b < 48)
                {
                    dumpDistro('tinycore');
                }
            }
            //q2a
            var q2a = document.getElementById('q2a').value;
            if ((stop == false) && (q2a == ''))
            {
                alert('Geen antwoord opgegeven bij vraag 2a!');
                stop = true;
            }
            if (stop == false)
            {
                if (q2a === 'nee')
                {
                    dumpDistro('debian-stable');
                    dumpDistro('debian-testing');
                    dumpDistro('debian-unstable');
                    dumpDistro('centos');
                    dumpDistro('archlinux');
                    dumpDistro('puppylinux');
                    dumpDistro('dsl');
                    dumpDistro('tinycore');
                    dumpDistro('gentoo');
                    dumpDistro('chakra');
                    dumpDistro('slackware');
                    dumpDistro('vector');
                    dumpDistro('mandriva');
                    dumpDistro('archbang');
                    dumpDistro('antix');
                }
            }
            //q2b
            var q2b = document.getElementById('q2b').value;
            if ((stop == false) && (q2b == ''))
            {
                alert('Geen antwoord opgegeven bij vraag 2b!');
                stop = true;
            }
            if (stop == false)
            {
                if (q2b === 'ja')
                {
                    dumpDistro('debian-unstable');
                    dumpDistro('centos');
                    dumpDistro('archlinux');
                    dumpDistro('archbang');
                    dumpDistro('puppylinux');
                    dumpDistro('dsl');
                    dumpDistro('tinycore');
                    dumpDistro('gentoo');
                    dumpDistro('vector');
                }
            }
            //q2c
            var q2c = parseInt(document.getElementById('q2c').value);
            if ((stop == false) && (document.getElementById('q2c').value == ''))
            {
                alert('Geen antwoord opgegeven bij vraag 2c!');
                stop = true;
            }
            if (stop == false)
            {
                if (q2c < 8)
                {
                    dumpDistro('gentoo');
                    dumpDistro('archlinux');
                }
                if (q2c < 7)
                {
                    dumpDistro('tinycore');
                }
                if (q2c < 6)
                {
                    dumpDistro('debian-unstable');
                    dumpDistro('centos');
                    dumpDistro('archbang');
                    dumpDistro('puppylinux');
                    dumpDistro('dsl');
                    dumpDistro('chakra');
                    dumpDistro('slackware');
                    dumpDistro('vector');
                    dumpDistro('antix');
                    dumpDistro('mandriva');
                }
                if (q2c < 5)
                {
                    dumpDistro('debian-testing');
                }
                if (q2c < 4)
                {
                    dumpDistro('crunchbang');
                }
                if (q2c < 3)
                {
                    dumpDistro('mintdebian');
                    dumpDistro('mintdebianxfce');
                    dumpDistro('debian-stable');
                    dumpDistro('fedora');
                    dumpDistro('fedorakde');
                    dumpDistro('fedoralxde');
                    dumpDistro('fedoraxfce');
                    dumpDistro('mandriva');
                }
            }
            //q3a
            var q3a = parseInt(document.getElementById('q3a').value);
            if ((stop == false) && (document.getElementById('q3a').value == ''))
            {
                alert('Geen antwoord opgegeven bij vraag 3a!');
                stop = true;
            }
            if (stop == false)
            {
                if (q3a == 4)
                {
                    dumpDistro('ubuntu');
                    dumpDistro('ubuntu-lts');
                    dumpDistro('elementary');
                    dumpDistro('fedorakde');
                    dumpDistro('opensuse');
                    dumpDistro('mageia');
                    dumpDistro('mint');
                    dumpDistro('mintlxde');
                    dumpDistro('lubuntu');
                    dumpDistro('kubuntu');
                    dumpDistro('xubuntu');
                }
                if (q3a == 3)
                {
                    dumpDistro('elementary');
                }
                else if (q3a == 1)
                {
                    dumpDistro('debian-unstable');
                    dumpDistro('debian-testing');
                    dumpDistro('fedoralxde');
                    dumpDistro('fedoraxfce');
                    dumpDistro('centos');
                    dumpDistro('archlinux');
                    dumpDistro('puppylinux');
                    dumpDistro('dsl');
                    dumpDistro('gentoo');
                    dumpDistro('mandriva');
                    dumpDistro('vector');
                    dumpDistro('antix');                
                }
            }
            //q3b
            var q3b = document.getElementById('q3b').value;
            if ((stop == false) && (q3b == ''))
            {
                alert('Geen antwoord opgegeven bij vraag 3b!');
                stop = true;
            }
            if (stop == false)
            {
                if (q3b == 'ja')
                {
                    dumpDistro('ubuntu');
                    dumpDistro('ubuntu-lts');
                    dumpDistro('debian-testing');
                    dumpDistro('debian-unstable');
                    dumpDistro('debian-stable');
                    dumpDistro('elementary');
                    dumpDistro('fedora');
                    dumpDistro('fedoralxde');
                    dumpDistro('fedoraxfce');
                    dumpDistro('centos');
                    dumpDistro('archlinux');
                    dumpDistro('crunchbang');
                    dumpDistro('archbang');
                    dumpDistro('pinguyos');
                    dumpDistro('gentoo');
                    dumpDistro('mandriva');
                    dumpDistro('xubuntu');
                }
                if (q3b == 'neevoorwaarde')
                {
                    dumpDistro('debian-testing');
                    dumpDistro('debian-unstable');
                    dumpDistro('debian-stable');
                    dumpDistro('fedora');
                    dumpDistro('centos');
                    dumpDistro('archlinux');
                    dumpDistro('pinguyos');
                    dumpDistro('gentoo');
                    dumpDistro('mandriva');
                    dumpDistro('xubuntu');
                }
                if (q3b == 'neemacos')
                {
                    dumpDistro('debian-testing');
                    dumpDistro('debian-unstable');
                    dumpDistro('debian-stable');
                    dumpDistro('fedora');
                    dumpDistro('fedoralxde');
                    dumpDistro('fedoraxfce');
                    dumpDistro('centos');
                    dumpDistro('archlinux');
                    dumpDistro('crunchbang');
                    dumpDistro('archbang');
                    dumpDistro('gentoo');
                    dumpDistro('mandriva');
                    dumpDistro('mageia');
                    dumpDistro('xubuntu');
                    dumpDistro('mint');
                    dumpDistro('mintdebian');
                    dumpDistro('mintlxde');
                    dumpDistro('mintdebianxfce');
                    dumpDistro('fedorakde');
                    dumpDistro('puppylinux');
                    dumpDistro('lucidpuppy');
                    dumpDistro('dsl');
                    dumpDistro('lubuntu');
                    dumpDistro('kubuntu');
                    dumpDistro('chakra');
                    dumpDistro('slackware');
                    dumpDistro('zorin');
                    dumpDistro('vector');
                    dumpDistro('antix');
                    dumpDistro('opensuse');
                }
            }
            //q3c
            var q3c = document.getElementById('q3c').value;
            if ((stop == false) && (q3c == ''))
            {
                alert('Geen antwoord opgegeven bij vraag 3c!');
                stop = true;
            }
            if (stop == false)
            {
                if (q3c == 'ja')
                {
                    dumpDistro('debian-stable');
                    dumpDistro('debian-testing');
                    dumpDistro('debian-unstable');
                    dumpDistro('centos');
                    dumpDistro('gentoo');
                }
            }
            //q3d
            var q3d = document.getElementById('q3d').value;
            if ((stop == false) && (q3d == ''))
            {
                alert('Geen antwoord opgegeven bij vraag 3d!');
                stop = true;
            }
            if (stop == false)
            {
                if (q3d == 'stabiel')
                {
                    dumpDistro('ubuntu');
                    dumpDistro('mintdebian');
                    dumpDistro('mintdebianxfce');
                    dumpDistro('debian-unstable');
                    dumpDistro('debian-testing');
                    dumpDistro('fedora');
                    dumpDistro('puppylinux');
                    dumpDistro('dsl');
                    dumpDistro('pinguyos');
                    dumpDistro('mandriva');
                    dumpDistro('kubuntu');
                    dumpDistro('chakra');
                    dumpDistro('slackware');
                    dumpDistro('opensuse');
                }
                else if (q3d == 'test')
                {
                    dumpDistro('debian-stable');
                    dumpDistro('debian-unstable');
                }
                else if (q3d == 'experimenteel')
                {
                    dumpDistro('debian-stable');
                }
            }
            if (distros.length > 6)
            {
                if ((q1a > 1000) && (q1b > 1000))
                {
                    dumpDistro('mintlxde');
                    dumpDistro('mintdebianxfce');
                    if (distros.length > 3) { dumpDistro('fedoralxde'); }
                    if (distros.length > 3) { dumpDistro('fedoraxfce'); }
                    if (distros.length > 3) { dumpDistro('mintdebianxfce'); }
                    if (distros.length > 3) { dumpDistro('lucidpuppy'); }
                    if (distros.length > 3) { dumpDistro('crunchbang'); }
                    if (distros.length > 3) { dumpDistro('dsl'); }
                    if (distros.length > 3) { dumpDistro('tinycore'); }
                    if (distros.length > 3) { dumpDistro('bodhi'); }
                    if (distros.length > 3) { dumpDistro('antix'); }
                    if (distros.length > 4)
                    {
                        if (q3b != 'ja')
                        {
                            dumpDistro('zorin');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (error)
        {
            alert(error);
        }
    }
    function dumpDistro(distro)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < distros.length; i++ )
        { 
            if (distros[i] == distro)
            {
                distros.splice(i,1); 
            }
        } 
    }
</script>
```

`var stop = false;` so let's remember that.

```
if ((stop == false) && (document.getElementById('q1a').value == ''))
            {
                alert('Geen antwoord opgegeven bij vraag 1a!');
                stop = true;
            }
```

Doesn't fire when input has content.

```
if ((stop == false) && (document.getElementById('q1b').value == ''))
            {
                alert('Geen antwoord opgegeven bij vraag 1b!');
                stop = true;
            }
```

Doesn't fire when input has content.

```
  if ((stop == false) && (q2a == ''))
            {
                alert('Geen antwoord opgegeven bij vraag 2a!');
                stop = true;
            }
```

Doesn't fire when input has content.

```
 if ((stop == false) && (q2b == ''))
            {
                alert('Geen antwoord opgegeven bij vraag 2b!');
                stop = true;
            }
```

Doesn't fire when input has content ... and so on...

Can you post the specific alert you think should fire even when no values are empty?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that's not the issue :p The problem is that it also does not show the alert on the end of the zoekDistro() function.

Comment: @RobinJ The error isn't happening because there is nothing wrong with your code, the calls are made and no built in errors are triggered to handle so your try catch succeeds. Failing an `if` doesn't trigger an error. My code definitely solves the problem of no alert appearing as your alert in your if now functions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, either you understand the question wrong, or I understand your answer wrong... Anyway, I did what you told me, to no effect. If everything is filled in, and one clicks the submit button, nothing happens. By the way, I wanted the first answer to be selected by default. The check I they were empty in the javascript code was just done in case I every changed my mind about that.

Comment: @RobinJ I misunderstood what you wanted, but what are you expecting to happen? you haven't told it to do anything except `distros.splice(i,1);`... this won't make your page change.

Comment: Take a good look at the script. No matter if the script fails or not, it should at least pop up an alert.

Comment: @RobinJ This is not the case I will break down your script in an answer and show how there is no alert.

Answer (score 0):

Having a quick look in the code I can see a submit button with an onclick handler which appears to be working.

However there is no FORM tag surrounding the fields and the submit button so the browser does not know what to submit and to where.

Comment: As I thought, this makes no difference as I'm just using the onClick event of the button.